# Variable width DIV using pixel minimum and maximum widths?

Tags: css

Kinda stuck on a small issue trying to use a div with a background image in the top left [a logo] not sure how to get this done.... since the variable width is not dependent on a percentage width... i.e.

- the maximum width of the div is 1200px
- the minimum width of the div is 900px

When someone resizes their browser I need that div to expand or contract depending on the viewport size.

Any thoughts on how I can do this [is this possible without javascript?]?

**UPDATE**

This is where I got to - seems to work well in most browsers until I hit IE7..

```
    <div id="viewport" class="[[*layout]]">

<div id="contentwrapper">

        <div class="wrapper logo">

            <div id="header">
                [[$TopNav]]
            </div>

            <div id="content" class="homepage">
                [[!If? &subject=`[[*id]]` &operator=`==` &operand=`1` &then=`[[$HomePageTpl]]` &else=`[[$DefaultPageTpl]]` ]]
            </div>

        </div>

</div>

<div class="wrapper footer">

    <div id="footer">

        <div id="footnav">[[$FootNav]]</div>

        <div id="copyright">[[$Copyright]]</div>

        <div id="news-feed">[[$NewsFeed]]</div>

    </div>  

</div>
```

```
    div {border: 1px dotted #ccc;}

div#viewport {width:100%;float:left;min-height:100%;position:relative;background-color:#000000;}

div#contentwrapper {width:100%;float:left;background-color:#ffffff;margin-top:8px;}

div#content, div#footer, div#header {float:right;width:900px;padding-left:100px;}

div#header {} 

.wrapper {
    margin:0 auto;
    height:150px;
    width:100%;
    max-width:1110px;
    min-width:1060px;
    text-align:left;
    }
.wrapper.logo {
    background:transparent 
    url(/assets/images/layout/anderson-lyall-consulting-group-logo.png) no-repeat left top;
    }

div#topnav {width:900px;float:right;margin:0 auto;border:1px solid #cc0000;}
```

Answer (score 4):

CSS has 2 properties for those scenarios, that work from IE7+ called:

- min-width: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/min-width
- max-width: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/max-width

That's probably what you are looking for, you could set the width to 100% first then add the min/max width to control it.

Comment: I thought those 2 properties were dependent on the content - not the viewport. I'll try the 100% width though.

Comment: Well as long as the content can grow (% based) you can set both a min and a max width in pixels.

Comment: It mostly works, yes. But I neglected to mention that the div needs to be centered.

Answer (score 2):

For a no-js solution on modern browser you can use CSS media queries like so

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
   div { width: 900px; }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
   div { width: 1200px; }
}
```

this  will automatically resize the `div` depending on your window width and not on the content. Media queries support: http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries

a simple proof-of-concept demo

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        div { margin: 0 auto; border: 1px red solid }
        div:after { display: block; }

        @media screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
           div { width: 900px; }
           div:after { content: " max-width is 1199px" }
        }

        @media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
           div { width: 1200px; }
           div:after { content: " min-width is 1200px" }
        }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>Resize your browser</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have - it does work an is a good answer - but the IE 7 & 8 support is not there for the media queries.

Comment: this is a solution without js as you asked. For older IE consider to always set the width to 900px or 1200px via js (depending on the innerWidth of window at onload event) or statically. it could be an acceptable kind of graceful degradation